# Laravel: How to change the password and username, server name and database?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have two domains and webservers and am trying to change from one webserver to another. My first webserver has  the laravel framework and I want to copy all the files and database to another webserver. How can I change the connection links and settings. I tried a lot to find the file to change the settings but no luck.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can look through your root, check for **.env** file. Alternatively you can check your **config/database.php** for connections.

Comment: I already tried that and changed the settings but its not working

Comment: In general this should all you need to change, now it will depend in your back-end. Do you have some errors?

Comment: I am not able to load the website. I have already changed the settings and webservers. The page does not loads

Comment: Then this should be in deployment problem, go check your public/index.php check if the directories are correct.

Comment: Dir looks fine. not sure whats the problem